# Better method to make pop up view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, alpha, subview

Let's assume we want to show some `popup` view on our screen. When user clicks a button our view pops up. In `popup` view we have `Close` button that hide/remove view itself.

Which method should I use to do that kind of thing:

1.) After click on the button add `popup` view to my main view. `Close` button removes popup view from superview.

or

2.) Make `popup` view with `alpha = 0` and after click a button change `alpha = 1`. `Close` button changes `alpha to 0`.

When I was adding and removing `view` by multiple clicking in buttons I have noticed that application started to slow down.
If you know good solution/method to do that kind of things (show view/views in another view) it would be very usefull.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Did you try using the standard UIViewController mechanisms for showing/removing popup views?

Comment: I just want to show a view with 3-4 labels in it, without any logic or actions except `Close` button. Do i really need to use UIViewController and there a view instead of just make simple UIView?

Comment: @Billy in this case i'd go with alpha as it is an animatable property. But if you are going to use it in different places better to create a view or viewController

Comment: @IvanAndrosenko Ok, thanks for Your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually UIKit treats very-low alpha elements as hidden but hidden elements still participate in autoresizing and other layout operations associated with the view hierarchy. To save your performance i'd recommend to use `addSubview`/`removeFromSuperview` methods when show/hide your view.

You can also use ViewControllers with standard animation like:

```
    let presentedVC: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("presentedVC") as ViewController
    presentedVC.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    presentedVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.presentViewController(presentedVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and when you tap Close inside your presentedVC use:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Does every other `view` that i want to add on my main `view` should has its own `UIViewController` ?

Comment: @Billy well there is no an exact answer, you should find a compromise depending on how often you are going to use this view, how much logic it will have and how fast you want to finish your screen:)